# What python distribution should I download for PsychoPy so that I won't run into version errors?

Tags: python, psychopy

It's been a painful weekend of learning how picky PsychoPy is...It only likes 32-bit Python above 2.5 and below 3, and many of the scripts have to be specific versions as well.

That said, I am currently using the distribution provided here (Option 1): http://gestaltrevision.be/wiki/python/pythoninstall , and so far it seems to work.

However, the PsychoPy documentation recommends getting a free academic license for Enthought: https://store.enthought.com/#canopy-academic , but I'm worried about running into more conflicts with the version of scripts etc.

I'm hoping any current PsychoPy users can share insight into their initial setup and what distribution they would recommend so I can hit the ground running and avoid more conflicts.

Comment: I understand the frustration you experience with compatibility issues, but the way you've worded this, makes it in my opinion unfit for stackoverflow. It seems better fit for a blog or disussion forum where many users can share their experiences, but there isn't one single answer that will stand out, as they are all valuable. If you're experiencing a real problem at the moment, and not a "how can I start fastest"-type of question, consider rewording your question to reflect the specifics of that problem.

Comment: Psychopy uses 32-bit python 2.7.x (currently the newest is 2.7.10). It will probably move to Python 3.X, but other features have higher priorities right now. One way to install psychopy is to use the anaconda installer. The recipe for psychopy is here: https://anaconda.org/erik/psychopy, but it's not the most recent version of psychopy.

Comment: The best idea is simply to install the Standalone version which includes their own copy of Python and all the dependencies. I know there are many versions of Python and incompatible libs and that's why we built the Standalone distribution.

The need for 32bit is mostly outdated and relates to the dependencies, not PsychoPy itself. On Mac all the dependencies can now be used under 64bit (but you might need to do some compiling yourself). On windows I don't know whether the sounds lib (pyo) is available in 64bit but I think most other things are. The question of Python3 is on its way.

Comment: @OliverW. I understand why you might see it like that, but I would disagree. Many of the questions on this site have multiple concrete answers, and I believe that is the case for my question. I'm simply looking for a name of a distribution. As with answers that help figure out code, some are better than others - so I expect that to be the case here too. Perhaps my use of the word "insight" made it sound like I was asking for opinions, when in fact I'm asking for clarification on why a particular distribution would be helpful (as one might also clarify how their code is helpful).

Comment: @Jon Thanks! I'll checkout the Standalone version, I didn't expect a response from the creator of PsychoPy haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a good idea to look at `virtualenv` and install specific python distros for your different projects. 
Even faster, you could install `docker` and `kitematic`. I'm using it for TensorFlow, since I had similar troubles getting the proper installation going. I found a 'psychopy` image there, but can't tell you anything about it's usability.
[image]